# Change the product variant by clicking on the variant image Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, variant

I have shop created in wordpress with woocommerce. I have a question. How i can do when i want change the product variant by clicking on the variant image ? When i select product variant in dropdown, image changes. But when i click on variant image, dropdown will not change. Any solution ? Thank you.

Comment: Please consider being clearer in your question. Use screen images if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIElr.png)

You can see it on picture. I click on belt color type "BROWN" and on left side in product variant i still have another color type "BLACK". Color variant not change after clicking picture variant.